# Using Jest Fake Timer in react-testing-library act() with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using Jest along with [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library), and encountered this warning when simulating advancing the timer:

```
 console.error
      Warning: An update to TimerProvider inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
      
      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
      
      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

After some searching, I found [a video suggesting wrapping any calls to `jest.advanceTimersByTime` in the `act()` function](https://egghead.io/lessons/jest-fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning-with-jest-fake-timers).

```
act(() => jest.advanceTimesByTime(1000);
```

However I am using TypeScript and am now confused as to how to resolve the resultant type error:

```
TS2769:Type 'typeof jest' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

How do I fix this type error correctly?

Comment: In video is suggested `act(() => jest.advanceTimesByTime(1000);` , have you tried instead  `act(() => { jest.advanceTimesByTime(1000); };`  ?

Comment: @Rostyslav yes, sorry edited for clarity

Comment: So you tried both ways mentioned in the comment above and both give same error? If yes than problem is somewhere else in the test code

Answer (score 6):

I met the same problem as you and converting to regular function with curly braces prevent the type error:

```js
act(() => {
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
});
```

Comment: That this fixes the error is both good and horrifying

Comment: This fixes it because jest.advanceTimersByTime is not `void`, but act expects any function inside it to be void. So wrapping it in brackets accomplishes that. You can avoid the brackets if you do `act(() => jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000) as any)`